# How to keep symlinks after deploy via AWS CodeDeploy from Git (Bitbucket)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, symlink, aws-code-deploy

I'm deploying files from Bitbucket via CodeDeploy tool. After deploy to EC2 instance symlinks become empty folders. Is there a way to keep symlinks after deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symlinks is now supported for artifacts, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.enable-symlinks).

In `buildspec.yml`:

```
artifacts:
  enable-symlinks: yes
```

Comment: Seems like you're talking about CodeBuild, but I think the question is about CodeDeploy, which uses `appspec.yml` instead of `buildspec.yml`.  There doesn't appear to be an analog in the CodeDeploy spec.

Answer (score 7):

Deployment will clean up the target folder before copying the new files.
You can add hooks to `appspecs.yml` for `AfterInstall` to create the symlinks again.

```
hooks:
    AfterInstall:
      - location: /deploy/AfterInstall.sh
        timeout: 3000
        runas: root
```

then in file `AfterInstall.sh` add the command to create symlink

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink
```

Comment: Thank you Ankit! I also thought about that but was hoping there is some out of box solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can put this code into a script that runs as part of the deploy:

```
files=$(find . -type f -exec awk 'END { if (NR == 1) print FILENAME }' {} \;)

for file in $files ; do
  pushd $(dirname $file)
  contents=$(cat $(basename $file))

  if [ -f $contents ] ; then
    rm $(basename $file)
    ln -s $contents
  fi

  popd
done
```

Essentially, this will find any one line files in the repo, and for each file check if it's a path to another file (relative to where the symlink file was) and recreate the symlink.